# Get the installed Safari version using AppleScript or Objective C

Tags: objective-c, safari, applescript, version, macos

How can I check the installed safari version on Mac? I need to provide temporary fix for Safari as my app didn't work on safari 5.0.6 and 5.1. So how can I detect these 2 version of safari...

i can find its version using webkit but based on this site: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history

Safari 5.0.6 has the similar webkit as the previos version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Safari is running this AppleScript will get the version:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set safariVersion to version
end tell
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this even if Safari isn't running...

```
get version of application "Safari"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can read the version out of /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/version.plist.