# get the return value of command run in the terminal in c++

Tags: c++, shell, command-line, terminal

for now this is my code. This command will execute a script and supposed to return Safari browser version on Mac if its run in the Terminal.

```
int versionResult = system("osascript /Library/Application\\ Support/Version.scpt");
```

In C++, this wil return 1 or 0.

How can I make it return the result of the command in C++?

Comment: See also [Get the installed Safari version using AppleScript or Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155260/get-the-installed-safari-version-using-applescript-or-objective-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with `system`; there's no platform-independent way to do it without using a cross-platform framework like `Qt`. That looks like a Mac command; to do this on the Mac, which is Unix-like, you could use `popen()`, something like

```
char buffer[100];
FILE * f = popen("osascript /Library/Application\\ Support/Version.scpt", "r");
fgets(buffer, 99, f);
pclose(f);
```

`buffer` gets the output of the command as a character string.